# pwa - add multiple uri

Tags: javascript, symfony, google-chrome, progressive-web-apps

I use Symfony and I add PWA in my application ..in my application I use webpack I have two files js front.js and admin.js ..in two files I launch service worker and I create precache files js and CSS for home page '/', also I add '/admin' and '/offline' in precache..but in mode offline '/' and '/offline' is work but '/admin' doesn't work !!
this is manifest.json:

```
{
  "name" : "test",
  "short_name" : "test",
  "icons": [
    {
    "src": "img/icon72x72.png",
    "type": "image/png",
    "sizes": "72x72"
  },{
    "src": "img/icon96x96.png",
    "type": "image/png",
    "sizes": "96x96"
  },{
    "src": "img/icon144x144.png",
    "type": "image/png",
    "sizes": "144x144"
  },{
    "src": "img/icon-48x48.png",
    "type": "image/png",
    "sizes": "48x48"
  },{
    "src": "img/icon512x512.png",
    "type": "image/png",
    "sizes": "512x512"
  }, {
    "src": "img/icon-192x192.png",
    "type": "image/png",
    "sizes": "192x192"
  }],
  "theme_color" : "#1a1a1a",
  "background_color" : "#1a1a1a",
  "start_url" : "/",
  "display" : "standalone",
  "orientation" : "natural"
}
```

sw.js:

```
var CACHE = 'pwa';

        self.addEventListener('install', function(event) {
            event.waitUntil(
                caches.open(CACHE).then(function(cache) {
                    fetch('/get-all-files?url='+event.target.location.origin)
                        .then(
                            function(response) {
                                if (response.status !== 200) {
                                    console.log('Looks like there was a problem. Status Code: ' +
                                        response.status);
                                    return;
                                }
                                response.json().then(function(data) {
                                    data.forEach(function(element) {
                                        if(element){
                                            cache.add(element);
                                        }
                                    });
                                    cache.add('/');
                                    cache.add('/offline');
                                    cache.add('/build/front.css');
                                    cache.add('/build/images/hp-slider.ca2e5f82.jpg');
                                    cache.add('/build/images/background-commentcamarche.15892cd8.jpg');
                                    cache.add('/build/images/background-etapes.15c039e3.jpg');
                                    cache.add('/FrontOffice/images/logo-marypop-en.png');
                                    cache.add('/FrontOffice/images/logo-marypop-fr.png');
                                    cache.add('/FrontOffice/images/logo-marypop-de.png');
                                    cache.add('/admin/');
                                    return true;
                                });
                            }
                        );
                })
            );
        });

        self.addEventListener('activate', function(event) {
            event.waitUntil(
                caches.keys().then(function(CACHE) {
                    return Promise.all(
                        CACHE.filter(function(CACHE) {
                            // Return true if you want to remove this cache,
                            // but remember that caches are shared across
                            // the whole origin
                        }).map(function(CACHE) {
                            return caches.delete(CACHE);
                        })
                    );
                })
            );
        });

        self.addEventListener('fetch', function(event) {
            event.respondWith(
                caches.match(event.request)
                    .then(function(response) {
                        // Cache hit - return response
                        if (response) {
                            return response;
                        }
                        return fetch(event.request).then(
                            function(response) {
                                // Check if we received a valid response
                                if(!response || response.status !== 200 || response.type !== 'basic') {
                                    return response;
                                }
                                var responseToCache = response.clone();
                                caches.open(CACHE)
                                    .then(function(cache) {
                                        cache.put(event.request, responseToCache);
                                    });

                                return response;
                            }
                        ).catch(function(err) {
                            return caches.open(CACHE)
                                .then(function(cache) {
                                    return cache.match('/offline');
                                });
                        });
                    })
            );
        });
```

how to add `'/'` and `'/admin'` (part of the dashboard to precache) also when I add `'/register'` in precache it works in mode offline

Comment: `manifest.json` does not have any impact on what does and does not work offline. Please update to include service worker code/config.

Comment: @abraham I update answer and i add service worker

Comment: You are caching `/admin/` but it looks like your visiting `/admin`. Those are different resources. Make sure the cached and visited paths are the same.

Comment: Where is event for update cache and not is fetch event ... exist another event ??